# access model from a plug in in zend

Tags: zend-framework, model

Does anybody know a simple way to access a model from a plug in  using zend.

I need to run queries in the plugin.

I have tried registering the dbadapter but that didn't work.

If so can you provide  a sample code.

thank  you.

Comment: You have register db adapter before defininf the code for plugin. You have to get Dbadapter from your model and you can create the object of model from plugin.

Comment: Amit i am able to registe and create an object from the plugin.But when i run a select i get the following error:
'
Zend_Db_Select::__construct() must be an instance of Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract
'
Any ideas?